# How do I create a chart in Apache Superset that contains both the raw data and a rolling average?

Tags: apache-superset

How do I create a chart in Apache Superset that displays both raw data (line or bar) and a rolling average (line)?

I can figure out how to do this with legacy chart options (Line Chart/ Dual Line Chart/ Multiple Line Charts) but they are labelled Legacy or Deprecated. The new option seems to be Mixed Time-Series, but it doesn't look like this supports rolling averages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in Superset v2.0.0.  Select the chart template **Mixed Chart**, then complete the fields on the DATA tab: Shared query fields, Query A, Advanced Analytics Query A, Query B, Advanced Analytics Query B.

On one of the Advanced Analytics sections, specify `mean` for the `ROLLING FUNCTION` and values (probably the same) for `PERIODS` and `MIN PERIODS`.

Then on the CUSTOMIZE tab, select the `SERIES TYPE` for A and for B.  That lets you mix bars and lines.

And you should get a chart like this:
[image]